# EasyTracker with SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity, easytracker

I am having a hard time using Google Analytics EasyTracker in my Activities that extend SherlockFragmentActivity.
When I try to use `EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);`
 in onStart, the compiler doesn't complain but the app crashes with:

> **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0a0001**

If I try to do `EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);` in any method outside of onStart, I get the same exception.

I am having a hard time understanding what's going on here, or whether it is possible at all to use EasyTracker with FragmentActivities.

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: can you post the code related?

Comment: Nothing to post except the onStart method that crashes on EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);

Comment: did you try plain Activity instead fragmentactivity?

Comment: I have no issues with plain activities.  However, my app uses FragmentActivites specifically because I use FragmentManager.

Comment: i am not familiar with SherlockFragmentActivity, and i doubt maybe it's the problem source

Answer (score 0):

EasyTracker have the following method.

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
```

and the tutorial explained how to start:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ... // The rest of your onStart() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); // Add this method.
  }
```

According to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/

Comment: As I stated in my post, the onStart method crashes with "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0a0001"